# Sections of twisted vector bundle on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over the field of complex numbers. Let $E$ be a stable vector bundle on $C$ of rank $n$ and degree $d$ such $E$ has a subbundle  $E_1 \subset E$ with   $H^0({(E/{E_1})}^* \otimes E_1 \otimes K) \ne 0$, where $K$ is the canonical bundle on $C$. Let $E$ be a general stable bundle with this property and $E_1$  be a subbundle of $E$ of minimal slope such that $H^0({(E/{E_1})}^* \otimes E_1 \otimes K) \ne 0$. Further assume that $\chi({(E/{E_1})}^* \otimes E_1 \otimes K)\le 0$.

Question:
Can we say $h^0({(E/{E_1})}^* \otimes E_1 \otimes K) =1$ ?